# Uploaded attachment not set as featured image

Tags: plugin-development, images, attachments

The following code uploads an image which I want to associate with a custom post type.

```
$upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => FALSE );
if($file_errors['error'] == 0) {

  if($new_reseller_id = wp_insert_post( $new_reseller_profile_data )){

    //$this->wps_process_image($file, $new_reseller_id);exit;

    $uploaded_file = wp_handle_upload( $file, $upload_overrides );

    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($uploaded_file['file']), null );
    $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $attachment = array(
      'guid' => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $uploaded_file['file'] ),
      'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
      'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($file['name'])),
      'post_content' => '',
      'post_status' => 'inherit'
    );
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $uploaded_file['file'], $new_reseller_id );
    // you must first include the image.php file
    // for the function wp_generate_attachment_metadata() to work
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $uploaded_file['file'] );
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

  }
}
```

The image is uploaded and viewable in the image library but does not appear as the featured image in the custom post type editor. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to do the following:

```
set_post_thumbnail( $new_reseller_id, $attach_id );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `update_post_meta`

```
// Set Featured Image
update_post_meta($new_reseller_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id);
```